# PHP MySQL arrays SELECT, FROM, WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get a system where the array data is changed to match the ID of its entry on another MySQL table. I am getting this from checkboxes on a PHP script.

This is the code

```
$insertSQL2 = "INSERT INTO test (Testing) VALUES SELECT Course_id FROM courses WHERE Code IN ";
foreach ($_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] as $Q){
    $Q = mysql_real_escape_string($Q);
    $insertSQL2.= "('$Q'), ";
} 
$insertSQL2 = rtrim($insertSQL2, ", ");
```

I can get the raw data output when I want. e.g. when the four checkboxes are selected, they will be placed in the table in seperate rows (which I require). However when I try to change it to match the code (When the checked box = a code in the table, the id is placed instead of the code) I get the following error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL      
server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Course_id FROM courses WHERE 
Code IN ('CNMD'), ('EEM')' at line 1
```

Has anybody got any possible solutions?

Comment: WHERE CODE IN ('value1','value2','value3') is how it should look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` statements can use either `VALUES` or `SELECT` syntax. Not both.

You probably want the second:

```
INSERT INTO test (Testing) 
  SELECT Course_id 
  FROM courses 
  WHERE Code IN ('CNMD', 'EEM') ;
```

Comment: Have spent hours trying different methods, first time posting on this site. Cant believe it was because of values - select. You are a ledge Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your SQL sentence look like:

```
SELECT Course_id FROM courses WHERE Code IN ('CNMD', 'EEM')
```

So you PHP code would need to be something like:

```
$insertSQL2 = "INSERT INTO test (Testing) VALUES SELECT Course_id FROM courses WHERE Code IN (";
foreach ($_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] as $Q) {
    $Q = mysql_real_escape_string($Q);
    $insertSQL2.= "'$Q', ";
} 
$insertSQL2 = rtrim($insertSQL2, ", ");
$insertSQL2 .= ")";
```

Comment: or you could add $Q to array then implode using comma separator